# Permissão negada para dar push

Tags: github

Quando vou tentar dar push no meu repositório local aparece a mensagem:

> "remote: Permission to usuário/reoi.git denied to usuário. fatal: não
> foi possível acessar 'https://github.com/usuário/repo.git/': The
> requested URL returned error: 403"

Isso começou depois que desabilitei a autenticação por dois fatores, mas não sei se tem alguma relação.

Answer (score 1):

Autenticação via `https` foi desabilitada do GitHub em 13 de Agosto de 2021. Conforme esta [`postagem do blog`](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/).

Para resolver este problema é necessário trocar o seu método de autenticação para `chave SSH` ou `token`.

Para fazer esta configuração é necessário fazer o login no Github e Adicionar uma nova chave privada à sua conta. Se não possui uma chave SSH gerada, o GitHub possui um tutorial que ensina a gerar esta chave. [`Ref`](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

Para isto basta acessar seu perfil no GitHub (estar logado):

1. Configurações (settings)
2. Chaves SSH e GPG
3. clicar no botão `Nova chave SSH`
4. Adicione sua chave

Após estes passos é necessário configurar o seu repositório (o repositório que está em sua máquina), para fazer o acesso via chave ssh:

1. acessar o diretório do repositório
2. executar o comando: `git remote -v`
3. Como está recebendo um erro 403 provavelmente a saída será algo do tipo:

   ```
   origin https://github.com/<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git (fetch)
   origin https://github.com/<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git (fetch)
   #       ⇑
   ```

O que é necessário prestar atenção é a parte do `https`, agora basta remover esta origin e adicionar a que utiliza chave ssh.

Para isso basta executar o seguinte comando (estou assumindo que está no repositório que está com o erro 403).

```
 git remote remove origin
 git remote add origin git@github.com:<seu-usuário>/<seu-repositório>.git
 #                                         ⇑              ⇑
```

Trocar os valores das variáveis `seu-usuário` e `seu-repositório` e tudo deve funcionar como esperado.

Após fazer essas alterações será possível utilizar o seu repositório `git` novamente.

No material passado como referência existe indicação de outras maneiras de autenticar sua conta que também são consideradas seguras.

### Solução de problemas

Se ao final do processo ao tentar fazer push;pull do repositório e estiver recebendo o erro:

> git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Verifique o endereço remoto da aplicação para acesso via SSH, este valor é fornecido pela interface gráfica do GitHub ao acessar o seu repositório e clicar  no botão *Code*

Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O valor exibido, deve ser igual ao valor do retorno do comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Caso não seja, repetir os passos da configuração do repositório com os valores corretos.

Comment: Obtive a seguinte saída: "git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.".

Comment: @ÍvanoFontes, adicionei mais alguns detalhes para tentar resolver o problema, está logo abaixo em Solução de problemas.

Comment: Já consegui resolver aqui. Obrigado pela dica. Foi de grande ajuda.